# relative imports doesn't work, looks like can't find the module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following situation, where *a* is a directory:

```
a/
  __init__.py
  first.py
  second.py
```

**__init__.py**

```
print('i\'m starting the directory')
__all__ = ['second', 'first']
```

**first.py**

```
print('hi, i\'m the first')
from . import *
```

**second.py**

```
print('hi, i\'m the second')
```

So when I run from the interactive prompt:

```
>>> import a.first
i'm starting the directory
hi, i'm the first
hi, i'm the second
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/antox/Scrivania/a/first.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import *
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'first'
```

Why doesn't it find the *first.py* module? I mean I expected to get no error; during the run of the import I thought that it could see that *first.py* was already loaded so there was no error, it just skipped to the next listed in `__all__`.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency

Comment: Add `import first, second` to `__init__.py`, and remove the `import` from `first.py`.

Comment: yes, I know there are other ways to get the same benefits, but I would like to understand what's going on in this case

Comment: What's going on is that `__init__.py` is being asked by `__all__` to expose `first`, but *it doesn't know what that is*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe how can't it know what `first` is? I am using relative import, looking in the directory it can find out that first is the `first.py` file

Comment: Because *"explicit is better than implicit"*. Modules don't go looking for names unless *specifically told to*, which we do using the `import` keyword. You can't expose names via `__all__` unless they're either defined in or `import`ed into the namespace.

Comment: So why does it import `second.py`?

Comment: That's done by `from . import *` before it fails. If you remove that line, note that `a.first` **and** `a.second` will give `AttributeError` after you `import a`.

Comment: I understand that removing `from . import *` generates an `AttributeError` when calling`a.first` and `a.second` because they weren't imported. But I can not still understand why, leaving all as I coded, when running `from . import *` `second.py` is imported and `first.py` generates an error

Comment: I'm with the questioner on this one. Usually, circular imports just work in Python unless you try importing an item from a module before it has been defined. However, in this case the `first` module is trying to import itself, which shouldn't fail, since a reference to its module object should have been put into `sys.modules` before its code is run. It's worth noting that both the wildcard and the relative import syntax in `from . import *` are red herrings. You get the same exception if you do `from a import first`.

Comment: @Blckknght that's exactly the reason why I have this doubt. So is this (not allowing a module to import itself with relative imports) a desired behavior or what? Because without using relative imports I can make a module import itself.

Comment: Hmm, after some more testing, it's only when you use the `from package import module` syntax that `module` importing itself fails. using `import package.module` works just fine. When you use the `from` syntax, naming the package with `.` or an absolute name both fail.

Comment: @Blckknght *"a reference to its module object should have been put into `sys.modules` before its code is run"* - not the case, as you can test with `import sys; print('a' in sys.modules)`, which will be `False` in `a.py`. I don't think the reference is added until the module has successfully loaded.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: then how to regular circular dependency situations work? If `a.py` imports `b`, but `b.py` imports `a`, they both succeed. I understood that this was because the module objects were included in `sys.modules` while their code was running, so whichever module got loaded second would find the other, even though its code had not yet finished.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think reference is not added in sys.modules if an `SyntaxError` occurred but in other cases it is added

Comment: Possibly related to: http://bugs.python.org/issue992389

Comment: So the problem is the during `from . import *` `sys.modules` isn't checked and an error is trigged? if I understood well this problem is resolved in python3.5

Comment: I've just installed python3.5a1 but still same issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a long-standing bug in the Python import machinery. The issue is that the a module is not added to its package's global namespace until after it has completely loaded. This breaks `from package import module` statements, if `module` is only partly loaded. You're still able to use `import package.module` though, which has for a long time had special support from the import system.

As [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe) commented, the Python developers have been aware of this issue [since 2004](http://bugs.python.org/issue992389). Since the issue only comes up when there are circular imports involving modules in packages, and circular imports are usually considered bad design, they did not put a very high priority on fixing it.

However, there has been recent progress! [A partial fix](http://bugs.python.org/issue17636) was added a few months ago, for Python 3.5, which has just had its first alpha release (the full release is scheduled for September). The fix still doesn't actually add `module` to `package` while it's being loaded, but instead adds an extra check to `from package import  module` statements so that they work anyway in circular import situations that previously raised an `ImportError`.

This doesn't fix the `from package import *` case however. The code for wildcard imports apparently still wants all of the names in `package.__all__` to actually be present in the module itself. It doesn't appear to check the `sys.modules` dictionary to check for modules that are still in the processes of being loaded.

So, what does this mean for your code? I think there are two important lessons: First, don't use circular imports if you can help it (instead try to factor out some code from the two modules into a third utility module). Second, don't use wildcard imports (if `first.py` used `from . import first, second` you'll have no error in Python 3.5).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see you put an answer. However I tried as you told me and I code a `first=0` in the **__init__.py** file and all just worked fine, but I can't undestand this trick. `__all__ = ['second', 'first']`: why didn't I get the same error for `'second'`? why didn't I have to insert a `second = 0` statement too? what the need to add explicitly and particularly just `first`? What's the mechanism?

Comment: I strongly suspect that putting `first=0` in `__init__.py` will lead to more confustion, not less. You'll end up with `a.first.first` being `0`, more likely than not, rather than a reference to `a.first`, which you'd usually expect. You don't have the same issue with importing `second` because it is able to load all the way without any circularity. When it finishes loading, it's entry in the `a` module is placed. The `first` module on the other hand is still loading, and so it can't be found in `a` (though if you name it directly, rather than using `*`, the new code in 3.5 will find it).

Comment: Oh gosh..I'm getting very confused, why do I have `a.first.first`? With `from . import *` I mean: import every module in this directory. Now, `first=0` is defined in the **__init__.py** file so I would expect it to be attached to the `a` directory module (which will be then overwritten during the import of `first.py`) so...I don't understand :-(

Comment: You'd get `a.first.first` if the import succeeds (which alas it doesn't), since the `first` module is going to be importing itself, as well as `second`. This is the "circular" part of the import, which causes the issue. If that's not what you want, you'll need to take a look at your code more closely and decide on a different statement!

Comment: Ok, got it. May I ask one more thing? Why do I get an `AttributeError` during the import? Wasn't more appropriate an `ImportError`? Because I get the same error I would get if I call `a.nothing` and I don't think I'm doing something like this